# Zynq Qspi Booting

Tags: arm, boot, zynq

I'm using *Arm DS-5 and Xilinx SDK* for developing programs on *Zynq* board. 
I'm trying to boot Zynq 702 board from Qspi Flash.
What I've done so far is generating FSBL project from Xilinx SDK, and combining it with my application using Bootgen tool in SDK, then program it into the flash.
There are several questions in my mind.

- DS-5 produces an .axf file, Bootgen requires an .elf file. Can I use
  the .axf file by just changing its extension to .elf or do I require
  some more steps?
- Is there a tool that shows the inner structure of an .axf file?
  Showing what is where?
- And how can I debug if I managed to boot from QSPI. For example I want to debug my application from the beginning of FSBL, is it possible? Because in Qspi Boot, When I power on the board, my application would start running and when I connect with JTAG, it would be in somewhere in my application.

Answer (score 1):

An AXF might have some extra ARM-toolchain magic in it (I'm not sure off-hand), but at heart it's an ELF file - the ARM toolchain provides [`fromelf`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0477k/index.html) for poking around inside them, but other tools like `readelf` and `objdump` also work.

I'm not familiar with the Zynq platform so I don't know any specific debugger tricks, but a general one is just to put an infinite loop at the start of your code (possibly using volatile or inline asm trickery if necessary to prevent optimisation) - once the debugger's connected and broken into it, you just move the PC past the loop and continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally halt QSPI-booted Zynq via JTAG and do whatever you want with it. However, there are some quirks. Sometimes Zynq goes into some kind of lockup, and JTAG doesn't work at all, and you need to power-cycle before retrying. Some not-so-well-written peripherial might die after starting software over JTAG, so you might need to re-load bitstream first. And there are some Vivado-related bugs (like the one where you cannot re-flash the board unless you downgrade to 2017.2 or change MIO2-6 pulls or patch the FSBL) but i'm not sure if they apply in your case.